# Mutually exclusive write for HDFS file?

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, bigdata

Basically, in my program, tasks would be appending to an HDFS file. However, I don't want two tasks to be appending the file at the same time. Is there a mechanism, where I have only one task appending to an HDFS file. Basically a mutex kind of mechanism.I also need such mutex when creating the file.

Comment: which version of Spark you are using ?

Comment: I am using Spark 1.6

Comment: any other findings rather than DataFrame .. please keep posted. I'd like to know if anything else is there. Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge you **cannot** have more than one handler writing to the same HDFS file.

This is not a Spark limitation, this is just how HDFS is designed. In HDFS files are immutable. You have a single writer per file and no appends after they are closed. This is great for big data and Spark since you always know that the same file will result in the same data.

The way to solve this in Hadoop is have each writer write their own file and then have a final MapReduce job to coalesce them into one file (if this is something that you really want to have).

Most of the time you can just work with these multiple files. The trick is to have the folder as you container; e.g., `/a/b/people` where the people folder has a lot of different files each contain different subset of "people". Spark has no problem reading multiple files and loading them in the same DataFrame or RDD.

Comment: Your second suggestion, that is exactly what I am doing, but the problem is that, I have to combine hundreds of files. If the producing part made only one file, then I would have reduced the overhead of reading so many files in the consuming part.

Comment: I think there is no way around it using HDFS. You can alternatively use HBase to store the data so that you don't have to manage data at the file level. Or you can add everything in a queue (say Kafka) and then have a one reader that reads from the Q and creates just one file.

Comment: @Marios: It can be achieved with DataFrames after spark 1.5(we have done that like below. To elaborate below answer, We are receiving messages from Messaging system for specific cobdate/business/env/ so we are making our folder structure of HDFS like cobdate/business/env/0-9(partitioned folders) in Ingestion side. In processing side, we are loading these partitioned folders from data-frame we are processing as per logic. For one particular business/cobdate/env there are multiple folders 0-9 and was able to save them as parquet-avro files(of-course not 1 file)

Comment: @Marios: What is SaveMode.Append in that case? how Data-Frame is handling it internally?

Answer (score 1):

DataFrames in Spark1.5 and above offer the ability to append to an existing DF on HDFS. Spark internally uses the techniques described by @marios in the other answer.

For example (in Java):

```
dataframe.write().mode(SaveMode.Append).
   format(FILE_FORMAT).partitionBy("parameter1", "parameter2").save(path);
```

If you check HDFS you will see (example of writing to "hello"):

```
-rw-r--r--   3 vagrant supergroup          0 2016-05-13 17:48 /home/hello/_SUCCESS
-rw-r--r--   3 vagrant supergroup        281 2016-05-13 17:48 /home/hello/_common_metadata
-rw-r--r--   3 vagrant supergroup       2041 2016-05-13 17:48 /home/hello/_metadata
-rw-r--r--   3 vagrant supergroup        499 2016-05-13 17:46 /home/hello/part-r-00000-182e0b9b-a15d-47f9-8a3e-07739d6f2534.gz.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 vagrant supergroup        499 2016-05-13 17:48 /home/hello/part-r-00000-a8cf0223-69b3-4c2c-88f6-91252d99967c.gz.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 vagrant supergroup        499 2016-05-13 17:46 /home/hello/part-r-00001-182e0b9b-a15d-47f9-8a3e-07739d6f2534.gz.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 vagrant supergroup        499 2016-05-13 17:48 /home/hello/part-r-00001-a8cf0223-69b3-4c2c-88f6-91252d99967c.gz.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 vagrant supergroup        499 2016-05-13 17:46 /home/hello/part-r-00002-182e0b9b-a15d-47f9-8a3e-07739d6f2534.gz.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 vagrant supergroup        499 2016-05-13 17:48 /home/hello/part-r-00002-a8cf0223-69b3-4c2c-88f6-91252d99967c.gz.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 vagrant supergroup        499 2016-05-13 17:46 /home/hello/part-r-00003-182e0b9b-a15d-47f9-8a3e-07739d6f2534.gz.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 vagrant supergroup        499 2016-05-13 17:48 /home/hello/part-r-00003-a8cf0223-69b3-4c2c-88f6-91252d99967c.gz.parquet
```

Please see different options of save modes suitable for your requirement [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.0/sql-programming-guide.html#save-modes)

If you are using Spark1.4
Please have look in to [SaveMode doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SaveMode.html)